# How can you connect Splice Machine with a Azure Database

Tags: azure-sql-database, splice-machine

I have a Java application which connects to a database in Azure SQL Server.
I have a local machine with a Splice Machine Community Edition.
What I want to do is connect my Java Application using the Splice Machine as a bridge to my SQL Server.

I've tried the connect command from splice:
connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://ServerName.database.windows.net:1433/DatabaseName;user=UserName;password=PassWordUser' AS NEW_DBNAME;

But I get this error: ERROR 08001: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://ServerName.database.windows.net:1433/DatabaseName;user=UserName;password=PassWordUser

In theirs documentation there is a reference to a application: https://docstest.splicemachine.com/splicetools_migratetool.html but it can't get a link to download the jar that it says you can download.
Do anyone know th place for the file? or if there is a form to install the jdbc driver.

Greets,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please download the JDBC Driver for Splice Machine from [JDBC Driver Download](https://www.splicemachine.com/get-started/jdbc-driver-download/).

You can also reference this document: [The Splice Machine JDBC Driver](https://doc.splicemachine.com/tutorials_connectjdbc_intro.html#JDBCDriver):

Our JDBC driver is automatically installed on your computer(s) when you install Splice Machine. You’ll find it in the jdbc-driver folder under the splicemachine directory; typically:

```
/splicemachine/jdbc-driver/splicemachine/jdbc-driver/
```

You can also download the driver from our JDBC Download site:
https://www.splicemachine.com/get-started/jdbc-driver-download/.

Hope this helps.